# Fetch correct stats from database

Tags: mysql, performance, join, query-performance

I am trying to get count of all quiz users who have made purchases. Main table for storing users is `user` and `quiz_client` is linked with user table. `sales_order` table holds data of users who have placed orders/made purchases.

I'm running the below query but it's taking forever, is there something wrong with the query?

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(user.id)
FROM
    cx_user
        JOIN
    quiz_client ON quiz_client.user_id = user.id
        JOIN
    sales_order ON user.email = sales_order.customer_email
```

Comment: Try to index the column `email` in tables which you used to join. Best practice is to avoid direct join based on string try using `email id` and map it in the sales_order table.

Comment: @James thanks for the help, adding index on customer_email table has speedup the query to 5 seconds!

Comment: If you replace instead of email to it's id(int) it will be much faster and check whether the other column in join is indexed..

Comment: All `JOIN`ed fields (exactly the) same datatype? And indexed as @James says? And `JOIN` on `INTEGER`s if possible (`SMALLINT` (32K - 64K `UNSIGNED`) or `MEDIUMINT` even better).

Comment: Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
COUNT(DISTINCT user.id)
```

Else you are counting "purchases", not "users".